# android cannot clear the data in listview before refreshing

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I've an app that displays a list of transactions. When i click a button to get the next day's transactions the listview still has the previous day's transactions appended to it. How can i clear the array or the adapter before the getView repopulates it?

I've tried clear() and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() but it still doesn't work.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.getrotalayout);

         setCurrentDateOnView();


        Log.e(TAG, "title = " + getTitle());
        Log.e(TAG, "super.title = " + super.getTitle());
        nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();
        date = nfcscannerapplication.getDate();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rotalist);
        intent = this.getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("rotaArrayBundle");
        if(array != null){
            array.clear();
        }
        array = (ArrayList<?>) bundle.get("rotaArray");

        arrayAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, array);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

.[update]

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.getrotalayout);

         setCurrentDateOnView();


        Log.e(TAG, "title = " + getTitle());
        Log.e(TAG, "super.title = " + super.getTitle());
        nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();
        date = nfcscannerapplication.getDate();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rotalist);
        intent = this.getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("rotaArrayBundle");

        array = (ArrayList<?>) bundle.get("rotaArray");

        if (arrayAdapter == null){

        arrayAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, array);
        }else{

            ((MySimpleArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).clear();

        }

        for(YourListItem item : yourNewDataArray){
            ((MySimpleArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).add(item);
        }



        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    }// end of onCreate

    private MySimpleArrayAdapter getListAdapter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arrayAdapter;
    }
```

.
[update2]

```
public class GetRota extends NfcBaseActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = GetRota.class.getSimpleName();
    ListView listView;
    Intent intent;
    String callID;
    DateTime date;
    NfcScannerApplication nfcscannerapplication;
    ArrayList<?> array;
    String needName = "";
    MySimpleArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    private DatePicker dpResult;
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.getrotalayout);

         setCurrentDateOnView();


        Log.e(TAG, "title = " + getTitle());
        Log.e(TAG, "super.title = " + super.getTitle());
        nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();
        date = nfcscannerapplication.getDate();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rotalist);
        intent = this.getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("rotaArrayBundle");

        array = (ArrayList<?>) bundle.get("rotaArray");

        if (arrayAdapter == null){

        arrayAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, array);
        }else{

            ((MySimpleArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).clear();

        }

//      for(YourListItem item : yourNewDataArray){
//          ((MySimpleArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).add(item);
//      }



        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    }// end of onCreate

    private MySimpleArrayAdapter getListAdapter() {

        return arrayAdapter;
    }

    public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

        dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datepicker1);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menurotadetails, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.previous:
            DateTime now2 = nfcscannerapplication.getDate();
            Log.e(TAG, "now2 = " + now2);
            DateTime dateTimePlusOne2 = now2.minusDays(1);
            Log.e(TAG, "now2 after -1 = " + dateTimePlusOne2);
            nfcscannerapplication.setDate(dateTimePlusOne2);
            DateTimeFormatter fmt2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d-MMM-Y");
            String nextDay2 = fmt2.print(dateTimePlusOne2);

            Intent i2 = new Intent(this, NfcscannerActivity.class);
            i2.putExtra("nextRota", nextDay2);
            i2.setAction("NEXT_ROTA");
            startActivity(i2);
            return true;

        case R.id.next:

            DateTime now = nfcscannerapplication.getDate();
            Log.e(TAG, "now = " + now);
            DateTime dateTimePlusOne = now.plusDays(1);
            Log.e(TAG, "now after +1 = " + dateTimePlusOne);
            nfcscannerapplication.setDate(dateTimePlusOne);
            DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d-MMM-Y");
            String nextDay = fmt.print(dateTimePlusOne);

            Intent i = new Intent(this, NfcscannerActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("nextRota", nextDay);
            i.setAction("NEXT_ROTA");
            startActivity(i);
            return true;

        case R.id.today:
            setCurrentDateOnView();
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            return true;

        default:

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }






    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // set date picker as current date
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                    day);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;



            DateTime spinnyTime = new DateTime(year, month+1, day, 1, 1);
            Log.e(TAG, "spinnyTime = " + spinnyTime);
            DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d-MMM-Y");
            String formattedSpinnyTime = fmt.print(spinnyTime);
            Log.e(TAG, "spinnyTime = " + formattedSpinnyTime);
            Log.e(TAG, "year = " + year);
            Log.e(TAG, "month = " + month);
            Log.e(TAG, "day = " + day);


            Intent i = new Intent(GetRota.this, NfcscannerActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("nextRota", formattedSpinnyTime);
            i.setAction("NEXT_ROTA"); 
            startActivity(i);

        }
    };








    private class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<?> list;

        public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<?> list) {

            super(context, R.layout.rotarowlayout);
            Log.e(TAG, "inside adapter constructor");
            this.context = context;
            this.list = list;

            if(list.get(6).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Out of range")){

                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(GetRota.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("No Rota Available Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Unable To View Rota For That Day");
                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



                    } }); 

                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rotarowlayout, parent,
                    false);

            TextView startTime = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rowstarttime);
            TextView duration = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rowduration);
            TextView status = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowstatus);
            TextView name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowclientname);

            String record = list.get(position).toString();
            String[] itemsInRecord = record.split(",");
            Log.e(TAG, "itemin record = " + itemsInRecord.length);
            String[] recordItem = new String[itemsInRecord.length];

            for (int x = 0; x < itemsInRecord.length; x++) {

                recordItem[x] = itemsInRecord[x];
                Log.e(TAG, "x = " + x);
            }

            startTime.setText("Start Time: " + recordItem[0]);
            duration.setText("Duration:" + recordItem[1]);
            status.setText("Status:" + recordItem[2]);
            name.setText("Client:" + recordItem[3] + recordItem[4]);
            callID = recordItem[5];
            needName = recordItem[6];

            return rowView;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.list.size();
        }

    }// end of adapter class

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        Log.e(TAG, "inside onItemClick");

        Intent intent = new Intent(GetRota.this, GetRotaDetails.class);
        intent.putExtra("callIDExtra", callID);

        startActivity(intent);

    }

}// end of GetRota
```

.

[update3]

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        // Get your ArrayList from getIntent.getExtras() here, and use my code from above
        Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("rotaArrayBundle");
        array = (ArrayList<?>) bundle.get("rotaArray");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.getrotalayout);

         setCurrentDateOnView();


        Log.e(TAG, "title = " + getTitle());
        Log.e(TAG, "super.title = " + super.getTitle());
        nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();
        date = nfcscannerapplication.getDate();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rotalist);
        onNewIntent(intent);
        //intent = this.getIntent();
        //Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("rotaArrayBundle");

        //array = (ArrayList<?>) bundle.get("rotaArray");

        if (arrayAdapter == null){

        arrayAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, array);
        }else{

            ((MySimpleArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).clear();

        }

//      for(YourListItem item : yourNewDataArray){
//          ((MySimpleArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).add(item);
//      }



        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    }// end of onCreate
```

Comment: You can just call listView.setAdapter(null); and then reset correct adapter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should keep the old adapter, and whenever you want to update the list you can do the following:

```
((MySimpleArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).clear();
for(String[] item : array){
    ((MySimpleArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).add(item);
}
```

You don't have to call `notifyDataSetChange()` either, since `clear()` and `add()` does it for you.

**EDIT:** Set `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in the manifest XML on your activity, then override the `onNewIntent()` method like this:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

**EDIT2:**

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.getrotalayout);

     setCurrentDateOnView();


    Log.e(TAG, "title = " + getTitle());
    Log.e(TAG, "super.title = " + super.getTitle());
    nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();
    date = nfcscannerapplication.getDate();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rotalist);


    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    ArrayList<String[]> array = (ArrayList<String[]>)getIntent().getBundleExtra("rotaArrayBundle").get("rotaArray"); 
    MySimpleArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, array);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
}
```

.

[update 4]

```
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){

                String s = new Integer(i).toString();

                 JSONObject jsonobject2 = (JSONObject) jsonObject1.get(s);
                 String startdate = jsonobject2.getString("StartDate");
                 String duration = jsonobject2.getString("Duration");
                 String callStatusName = jsonobject2.getString("CallStatusName");
                 String clientForeName = jsonobject2.getString("ClientForename");
                 String clientSurName = jsonobject2.getString("ClientSurname");
                 String clientCallId = jsonobject2.getString("CallID");
                 String needName = jsonobject2.getString("NeedName");

                 ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
                 arr.add(startdate);
                 arr.add(duration);
                 arr.add(callStatusName);
                 arr.add(clientForeName);
                 arr.add(clientSurName);
                 arr.add(clientCallId);
                 arr.add(needName);

                 Log.e(TAG, "arr size = "+arr.size());
                arrayList.add(i, arr);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return arrayList;


class TwoDimentionalArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void addToInnerArray(int index, T element) {
            while (index >= this.size()) {
                this.add(new ArrayList<T>());
            }
            this.get(index).add(element);
        }

        public void addToInnerArray(int index, int index2, T element) {
            while (index >= this.size()) {
                this.add(new ArrayList<T>());
            }

            ArrayList<T> inner = this.get(index);
            while (index2 >= inner.size()) {
                inner.add(null);
            }

            inner.set(index2, element);
        }
    }
```

Comment: L. Monos Hi, sorry i'm not 100% sure what you mean. I've updated the post with amended code but not sure how to add the new data to the adapter. The original array is an ArrayList that is poulated with several String[].

Comment: You should use my code after you called `setListAdapter(adapter)`. Otherwise than that, I don't know where you should put it, since I don't know how you want to show your new data. Every time you call `startActivity()` with the new `Intent` extras?

Comment: L. Monos Yes i'd like to show the new data every time startActivity() is called with a new Intent Extras. The Extras is an ArrayList of String[]. It's the String[] that i'd like to refresh the view with.

Comment: I've updated my post. I've amended the manifest. Have I amended the Activity correctly? I'm not sure how to use the for loop you've given me or where to put it. sorry new to android.

Comment: I updated my answer again, with how your Activity should look like

Comment: I've changed the code but it doesn't like ArrayList<String[]> array = (ArrayList<String[]>)getIntent.getBundleExtra("rotaArrayBundle").get("rotaArray"); getIntent cannot be resolved.

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo, it is `getIntent()` it's a method. I forgot the praentheses. I fixed the typo in the answer.

Comment: Sorry that was obvious(typo). It compiles but i'm afraid the old data is still appended to the new data.

Comment: Then the problem is with the array you put into the inten bundle. Check what data you pass to the activity

Comment: I've updated post again to show you how the arrays are constructed, if you'd like to have a look. It's just a simple String[] placed inside an ArrayList.

Comment: sorry the it's an arraylist of type TwoDimentionalArrayList<T> that hold another arraylist<String>. i'll update again.

Comment: Hi i found the problem. You were right it was to do with how the arrayList is set up. I initialized the arrayList in the webservice's constructor. i simply moved it to the method that constructs the arrays, this way the old data is wiped as it's initialzed on every method call. Thanks alot you've been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try by changing the order.

```
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Hi sorry it doesn't make a difference.